# What sections of Apple Health app are available via the x-apple-health:// URL scheme?

Tags: ios, url, healthkit

I want let users view the Weight section of Apple's Health app to allow them to see detailed data, etc. I manage to open the Health app via the URL scheme `x-apple-health://`, but I would like to send them directly to the right place, e.g. `x-apple-health://HealthData/measurements/Weight`. I have had no success after trying different paths that made some sense.

Anyone has a reference on this?

Comment: it doesn't seem the scheme is documented.

Answer (score 4):

Apple has not documented the `x-apple-health://` scheme for use by apps. Attempting to use it is like using SPI - even if you find something that works now, it is likely to break in a future version of iOS. You should file a Radar with Apple to request an API for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Radar: https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=50721003